# Connect to SQL Server 2008 from phpmyadmin panel

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I want to create some automatic procedures, from my MySQL server (used for eshop), connected to an SQL Server 2008, that my accounting software exists.

till now:

- Firewall allows connection already
- I have access locally to the SQL Server
- I have root access to centos server and phpmyadmin in order to create procedures

but I don't know how to communicate the between the servers and create the procedures.

Comment: phpmyadmin cannot connect to an ms sql server. Period. In general, it is not possible to connect from mysql to an ms sql instance, unless you write that functionality in a compiled UDF. Either you add the MySQL server as linked server to your ms sql server and pull the data from MySQL via that connection (if you can connect to MySQL directly from a remote host), or you need to create an application that can connect to both database servers and does the data transfer.

Comment: hm that looks logic. thank you